# Creating a JSON Object in views and passing it in HTML

Tags: javascript, json, django, django-views

**views.py - Django 2.0.2**

```
def hotels(request):
    list_of_hotels = Hotel.objects.order_by('hotel_name')
    template = loader.get_template('myapp/hotels.html')

    data = {}
    for each in list_of_hotels:
        data[str(each.hotel_name)] = 'null'
    json_data = json.dumps(data)

    context = {
        'list_of_hotels': list_of_hotels,
        'json_data': json_data,
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

**hotels.html**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s12">
        <i class="material-icons prefix">search</i>
        <input type="text" id="autocomplete-input" class="autocomplete">
        <label for="autocomplete-input">Search</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  var jsonObj = "{{json_data}}";
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
      data: jsonObj,
    });
  });
</script>
```

I'm trying to parse a JSON Object from Django views into a script located inside the corresponding HTML page. I tried everything, but it just doesn't seem to work. I searched Stack Overflow for about an hour now, and based on all the answers came to these snippets of code, which still don't work. Any leads on how to go about it would be highly appreciated!

P.S: In the script in hotels.html, the data takes in a JSON Object. For more details on the initialisation, refer to [this](http://materializecss.com/autocomplete.html).

P.P.S: I am an absolute noob in JavaScript/ jQuery.

Comment: Writing directly to a Javascript variable isn't safe. Have a look at [django-argonauts](https://github.com/fusionbox/django-argonauts) which provides utilities and an example for how to safely pass JSON to your template.

Comment: Thanks for the lead. I'll check it out and update the question. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution to my own problem after a lot of tries. Thanks to anyone who tried to help me. :)

**hotels.html**

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col s12">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="input-field col s12">
    <i class="material-icons prefix">search</i>
    <input type="text" id="autocomplete-input" class="autocomplete">
    <label for="autocomplete-input">Search</label>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
  var jsonObj = {{ json_data|safe }};
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
      data: jsonObj,
    });
  });
</script>
```

**views.py**

```
def hotels(request):

    list_of_hotels = Hotel.objects.order_by('hotel_name')
    template = loader.get_template('myapp/hotels.html')

    data = {}
    for each in list_of_hotels:
        data[str(each.hotel_name)] = None
    json_data = json.dumps(data)

    context = {
        'list_of_hotels': list_of_hotels,
        'json_data': json_data,
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```